# При использовании @ManyToOne обязательно в связанном классе использовать @OneToMany?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Я посмотрел 5-7 туториалов и даже, что-то похожее на документацию. И везде, указывалось, что если нужно создать связь в таблице «многие к одному», то обязательно следует создать в связанной таблице «один ко многим».
Например https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/onetomany
Используя `ORM`, сгенерировались у меня 2 таблицы.
`Order` и `Customer`
В order все красиво, там только нужные поля

id | name | CUST_ID

но в `Customer` из-за

```
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=com.acme.Order.class, cascade=ALL,
                mappedBy="customer")
    public Set getOrders() { return orders; }
```

получились поля

id | name | orders

Мне столбец `orders` не нужен. Я попробовал не добавлять `@OnetoMany`. А оставил только в сущности `Order` `@ManyToOne` и получил на выходе две таблицы, без лишних столбцов. Зачем везде просят использовать с `@ManyToOne` `@OneToMany`?

Comment: Для того, чтобы появлялись циклические зависимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто вас не просит это делать, скорее всего это совет, типа как лучший вариант, потому как `OneToMany` много способов, просто двунапрявляные связи в  `OneToMany` это так скажем универсальный вариант, где есть свои плюсы и минусы, но плюсов больше, по сравнению, с другими вариантами `OneToMany`. Сначала у вас была двунаправленая связь, что позволяло Вам, переносить состояние с родительской сущности на дочернюю, при чем дочерняя сторона знала, кто родитель, а когда вы ставите только с одной стороны или `OneToMany`, или же только с другой стороны `ManyToOne`, то только родительская сторона знает про дочернюю сторону, дочерняя ничего не знает о родителе, к тому же для двунаправленой связи, нужны еще методы синхнонизации, то есть много чего всякого чего нельзя описать здесь коротно и ясно.